# Select Cells in Column Up to End of Data in Adjacent Column on OSX

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection

I know there is a command to do this but I just can't find it.  The [answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/180345/apply-formula-to-a-range-of-cells-without-drag-and-drop) should have used this command but did not.

**Q**: Given an empty column (B) adjacent to a column populated with data (A). There is a way to:

1. Enter a formula in B#
2. Use **shortcut_1** to select from B# to the last cell in B to have adjacent data in A.
3. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to propagate the selected formula to the selected cells.

Does anyone know the keystroke for shortcut_1 on OSX?
On windows I think the shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> ([noted here](https://superuser.com/questions/285316/click-to-select-row-to-end-of-data-in-excel)).  However, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> brings up the application mode in OSX.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as Windows, but use the Command key instead of Ctrl: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd>

More shortcuts here: [Excel keyboard shortcuts for Mac OS](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Excel-keyboard-shortcuts-ef213435-a57e-4ce1-bac6-2b39f16cb121?CorrelationId=470549f3-9e6d-4da1-8748-3ddef5e75adb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I think there is yet another command to do exactly what is wanted. Also, OSX defaults this shortcut to the 'applications' command via Mission Control, so this needs to be disabled.

Comment: I thought you just needed one way, not all possible ways to do it. Please update your question if so. Ctrl+↓ is the default shortcut to Application windows via Mission Control. If B is your last column, you can also do Ctrl+Shift+End. Hope it helped either way!

Comment: I could swear that I used this shortcut before.  It really should be there if it isn't already, would be super useful.